I would like to add 9 months onto a field table that is a date and have it populate with forecast date 9 months later
I have a field in my attributes table called "Planted"
It is set as a date field.
I have created another field called "Harvest"(also a date field) which needs to display a date 9 months from the date entered in the "Planted" field.
I would like the "Harvest" field to auto populate when I enter in the date into the "Planted" field.
I am new to QGIS 3.38.1.

Use Field Calculator:
"Planted" + to_interval('9 months')

If you want an automatic update when you enter a Planted date set a default value in Layer Properties - Attributes Form:


Most people would expect that 2008-07-13 plus 9 month to give 2009-04-13 not 2009-04-09...(this is the result of adding the actual number of day rather than incrementing the month number by 9)

Something has to give, especially when you want 9 months on from a 31st and the month doesn't have a 31st. First day of the next month? Or last day of the +9 month?

Working with date is full of question with no good answer as mathematics and variable length units don't really match well…
